# matching datatype in python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I'm new to python and studying deep learning using Github codes.
I'm getting error `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes` so I tried to match the datatype.

old:

```
newFilename = fileGenre+"_"+str(fileID)
```

new:

```
newFilename = fileGenre+"_"+bytes(fileID)
```

but same error occured, so I want to know how to fix the error. fileGenre is byte varible which is from eyed3 module and fileID is int type variable.

this is part of code:

```
    for index,filename in enumerate(files):
       fileGenre = getGenre(rawDataPath+filename)
       genresID[fileGenre] = genresID[fileGenre] + 1 if fileGenre in genresID else 1
       fileID = genresID[fileGenre]
       newFilename = fileGenre+"_"+str(fileID) #in this line, i got error
       createSpectrogram(filename,newFilename)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only concat `str` to `str` so when you are trying to concat `str` and `bytes` this will raise an error. You can use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method to return a string decodes from given bytes.

Use:

```
newFilename = fileGenre.decode("utf-8") + "_" + str(fileID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

new_filename = "{}_{}".format(fileGenre, str(file_id))

Answer (score 1):

you can not use string between two bytes value concatenation ("_")

so you can use this -

newFilename = str(fileGenre)+"*"+str(fileID)
newFilename = fileGenre+"*"+str(bytes(fileID))